# @Host and Content uses and purpose in angular4

Tags: angular

What is meaning and purpose of @Host and Content in angular 4.
Can @Host be invoked in Angular components instead of directives?.
Can someone please help to understand following terms.

1. @View
2. @Host
3. @ChildView.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: where did you see `@View` and `@Host`? what is `Content `?

Comment: Read the https://angular.io/docs first?

Comment: @Joe Keene https://angular.io/api/core/Host

Comment: True but if you take a look at the code it's quite straight forward https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.3/packages/core/src/di/metadata.ts#L250